# Is there a better way of writing this code?

Tags: c#, delegates, .net-micro-framework

I have a class with a enum `DoStuff` with values `before`, `after`, or `none`. These names are not the true names, but it gets the point across. The class has a method `foo`.

What follows is a set of readonly properties, of different types, each of which looks as follows:

```
public [type] MyProperty {
    get {
        if(enumValue == DoStuff.Before)
            foo();

        [type] result = //Do calculations here

        if(enumValue == DoStuff.After)
            foo();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of abstracting these pre/post-calculation calls out? I can currently think of two solutions:

- Create a private method that takes a delegate, and calls `foo` in the appropriate place. Complicated by the lack of generics on the platform I'm writing this for.
- Make an uninstantiable base class with neither wrapper call, and derive a Before and After subclass that accesses the base class' properties, with the call in the appropriate place

Is there a well known pattern for this kind of structure?

Comment: As a general comment on style, I would avoid altering the state within a property getter except for initialization purposes.

Comment: @Reddog: `foo()` is not a state-altering call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method with this syntax:

```
delegate void Handler();

void DoHandler(Handler handler)
{
        if(enumValue == DoStuff.Before)
            foo();

        handler();

        if(enumValue == DoStuff.After)
            foo();
}
```

Then in your property

```
public [type] MyProperty 
{
    get 
    {
        [type] result = default(type); 
        DoHandler(() => 
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 6;
            result = a + b;
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems with that. Firstly, that requires me to write a `DoHandler` function for each type of return value, which makes the code messier, not cleaner. Secondly, I said in the question that I have no generics support, so no `Func<type>`.

Comment: well, you can do it slightly different then.  I'll modify it then.

Comment: Can you do closures within lambdas in c#?

Comment: Closures as in `{ }`?  A lambda is a short-hand function, so whatever you can do with functions you can do with lambda's (and more with lambda's, as you can see it assigns to a variable outside the function scope).  Modified lambda some so maybe it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to create a Before and After event/delegate and slap foo() in the appropriate place, probably wherever you're setting enumValue right now.  Then call:

```
get {
   BeforeDelegate();
   // Do calcs
   AfterDelegate();
}
```

What's the practical use?  Why do you need this pattern?

Sidenote:  If I have a getter doing that kind of logic I'm more likely to put it in a method.  It's less likely to surprise folks.  Methods insinuate that I probably did something under the hood to get the value you asked for beyond just exposing a scalar value.

Comment: The code is to interface with a piece of hardware, so it seems reasonable to use properties (since they are properties of the hardware). [The hardware](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/HMC6352.pdf) has three modes: update continuously (`Continuous`, aka `DoStuff.None`), update when requested (`Standby`, aka `DoStuff.Before`), and update after read (`Query`, aka `DoStuff.After`).

Comment: Hmmm...  I'd still be more comfortable with a `GetPropertyValue()` call but it's a nitpicky thing to begin with.  Is there anything other than `foo()` that happens in the decision points?  I don't think this is a "best pattern" question so much as a "concise semantics" thing.  If that's all that happens and this is the only property where it happens, then the enum approach is pretty clear.  If this happens all over the place then I'd be inclined to go with the delegate/event approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to put enum value in a seperate class that has 1 property named EnamumValue and to event BEfore and After,and handle this to event in the class that uses enamvalue class,
when enumvalue changes fire appropriate Event

```
public class EnumValueClass
{

    public event BeforeDelegate OnBefore();
    public event AfterDelegate OnAfter();
    private EnumType enumValue;
    public EnumType EnumValue
    {
        get {
            return enumValue;
        }
        set{
            this.enumValue = value;
            if(enumValue == DoStuff.Before)
                if(OnBefore!=null)
                    OnBefore();

            if(enumValue == DoStuff.After)
                if(OnAfter!=null)
                    OnAfter();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fit the contract of the call. Firstly, `OnAfter` is the same function as `OnBefore`. More importantly though, the method `foo` must be called either before or after most property accesses. It does not need to be called when the mode is changed.